# Rendering mouse positions using document.write object

Tags: javascript

In the below code,

```
     <script>
            var mie = (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") ? true : false;
            if(!mie){
                document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);
            }
            document.onmousemove = mousePos;

            var mouseX = 0;
            var mouseY = 0;

            function mousePos(e){
                if(!mie){
                    mouseX = e.pageX;
                    mouseY = e.pageY;
                }
                else{
                    mouseX = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
                    mouseY = e.clientY + document.body.scrollRight;
                }

                /*document.formex.mousex.value = mouseX;
                document.formex.mousey.value = mouseY;*/
                document.write("X: " + mouseX + ";Y: " + mouseY + ";  Time: " + new Date());    
                return true;
            }
    </script>
```

---

the expected output is to render every new entry for every mouse position on move.

I could render only one entry with one mouse position using `document.write` object. Is there a better approach to render?

Comment: use `console.log` :)

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GoopvW?editors=001

Answer (score 0):

`document.write` [clears the document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/open#Notes) and all the event handlers inside it

try this instead

```
<script>
            var mie = (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") ? true : false;
            if(!mie){
                document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);
            }
            document.onmousemove = mousePos;

            var mouseX = 0;
            var mouseY = 0;

            function mousePos(e){
                if(!mie){
                    mouseX = e.pageX;
                    mouseY = e.pageY;
                }
                else{
                    mouseX = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
                    mouseY = e.clientY + document.body.scrollRight;
                }

                /*document.formex.mousex.value = mouseX;
                document.formex.mousey.value = mouseY;*/
                document.write("X: " + mouseX + ";Y: " + mouseY + ";  Time: " + new Date());    
document.onmousemove = mousePos;
                return true;
            }
    </script>
```

Observe the new statement added before `return true` to bind the event again.

or simply use this line instead of `document.write` (courtesy @Tom)

```
document.body.innerHTML = "X: " + mouseX + ";Y: " + mouseY + "; Time: " + new Date();
```

if you want to append then do

```
document.body.innerHTML += "X: " + mouseX + ";Y: " + mouseY + "; Time: " + new Date() + " </br>";
```

Comment: While this re-binds the javascript, it still wipes out the entire page. One should consider something such as `document.body.innerHTML = "X: " + mouseX + ";Y: " + mouseY + ";  Time: " + new Date());`

Comment: @Tom Yes, that is also true

Comment: JavaScript can be funny. I remember playing with iframes, and I was able to create an iframe with a function and put a reference to it in the outer scope, then delete the iframe and call the function. It was fun. No environment, just runtime.

Comment: @Tom But i need a new entry with every new position.

Comment: I'll help, overexchange. Check my answer in a sec.

Comment: @overexchange in that case append this line `document.body.innerHTML += "X: " + mouseX + ";Y: " + mouseY + "; Time: " + new Date()) + " </br> "; `

Answer (score 0):

Do not use document.write instead use **innerHTML**. Please refer to demo link.

> ```
>         var mie = (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") ? true : false;
>         if(!mie){
>             document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);
>         }
>         document.onmousemove = mousePos;
>
>         var mouseX = 0;
>         var mouseY = 0;
>
>         function mousePos(e){
>             if(!mie){
>                 mouseX = e.pageX;
>                 mouseY = e.pageY;
>             }
>             else{
>                 mouseX = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
>                 mouseY = e.clientY + document.body.scrollRight;
>             }
>
>
>             document.body.innerHTML = "X: " + mouseX + ";Y: " + mouseY + ";  Time: " + new Date();    
>             return true;
>         }
> ```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ashokkumargupta/LLef22da/)

Thanks,

Ashok